# Python Numpy array conversion

Tags: python, numpy

I've got 2 numpy arrays x1 and x2. Using python 3.4.3

```
x1 = np.array([2,4,4])
x2 = np.array([3,5,3])
```

I would like to a numpy array like this:

```
[[2,3],[4,5],[4,3]]
```

How would i go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
In [40]: x1 = np.array([2,4,4])

In [41]: x2 = np.array([3,5,3])

In [42]: np.column_stack((x1, x2))
Out[42]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 3]])
```

Comment: Pretty nice! Numpy built-in solution. I didn't know that.

Comment: Thank you!, this is perfect

Answer (score 2):

Yep. It sounds like zip function:

```
import numpy as np 

x1 = np.array([2,4,4])
x2 = np.array([3,5,3])

print zip(x1, x2) # or [list(i) for i in zip(x1, x2)]
```

Comment: The OP specifically asks for the output to be a numpy array

Comment: @mtrw Yep! You're right. The Warren's answer is the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can `zip` the 2 arrays like this:

```
x3 = list(zip(x1,x2))
```

Output:

```
[(2, 3), (4, 5), (4, 3)]
```

This above code creates a `list` of `tuples`. If you want a `list` of `lists`, you can use `list comprehension`:

```
x3 = [list(i) for i in list(zip(x1,x2))]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3], [4, 5], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: The OP specifically asks for the output to be a numpy array

Comment: @mtrw This is what the OP posted as a desired output: `[[2,3],[4,5],[4,3]]`. Yes, I know he called it a numpy array...